# Zoom videos call APIs & SDK not working on Heroku servers

Tags: heroku, sdk, zoom-sdk

Zoom API for video call are working fine on Windows OS but aren't working on linux based systems. Similar issue while deploying SDK to cloud based platforms like Heroku.

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/video/web

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Can you provide a little description of what you have tried ?